# asp.net publish site problem- pages with DB are not found (404)

Tags: asp.net

i'm using VS 2008, asp.net, framework 3.5

this is the first time i built an asp.net website.
the site is quite simple, with some pages getting there text onLoad from a DB (ms access),
and some with plain text.

it works fine on debugging.

i used publish web site, and got a preCompiled website folder on my computer.

i copied all the files to my hosting server.
the pages that don't need DB work fine, all the ones that call the DB on loading are not found.

i thought it was permissions, but the hoster checked it up with me. the db folder has all permissions.

i have 2 questions:
1. how do i get exact info on the error, better than 404 ??
2. what's happening? why doesn't it work?

thanks for reading this far..

Answer (score 0):

I know it sounds obvious but did you leave your testing connection string in the web.config or where so ever you keep it?

You may have used an alias for the DB you are using on your local machine but your ISP will not have the same alias. That would be my first port of call.

To get a better error message you could turn off [custom errors in your web.config](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc%28VS.71%29.aspx) and perhaps use [trace.axd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972204.aspx).

Comment: thanks. i shut off custom errors. now i only get:
" Server Error in '/' Application. "

not really helpful. reading about the trace.
remember- i'm fresh from the package. nothing is obvious to me. what is the testing connection string? i have only one connection string.
and another question: i read about misplaced bin folder. how do i check if it's misplaced? 
thanks a lot anyway!